# A machine spits out the product

Tags: phrases, verbs

So what's the opposite of feeding material to a machine? Are products ejected or discharged? While I think this may apply to a fast process where the product gets tossed out or dumped onto a hopper/bin, what is an appropriate term for a slower process?

> The oven __ the pizza.
>   The pizza is __ from/by the oven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I think the most common phrase would be "the pizza emerges from the oven". Similarly, a photograph would emerge from a printer (although text documents may well be spit out of some of the larger production printers).

I can also imagine a process like this being phrased in terms of the mechanism performing the action rather than the machine as a whole. For example, "the conveyor belt moves/carries the pizza from the oven to the holding area".

Comment: I'm not sure [emerge](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emerge) nails it, but "the pizza is moved out of the machine with the conveyor belt" seems OK to me - thanks,

Answer (score 0):

"to emit" is a nice term.  Another that popped in my head immediately was "disgorged", but that is *sloooow*.  Or at least it sounds that way (and it sounds slightly disgusting).

Comment: I only know of emission in the context of radiation or particles (but I'm not a native speaker).